# How to achieve an interrupt frequency of 100 kHz on SAM E70?

Tags: microcontroller, timer, interrupts, atmel

Setup: *ATMEL Studio 7, ASF3.47.0, SAME70 XPlained eval board.*

In the minimum working example shown below, I use the onboard LED for visualizing if the timer and interrupt enabling have executed. `PIO_PD20` is used to check if the interrupt is working. For that I simply connected my oscilloscope probe to `MISO` on the six-pin header near the center of the board. The code below works as expected up to frequencies of 2287 Hz. Once I choose frequencies higher than that, the interrupt doesn't seem to get triggered. What am I doing wrong? I need this to clock at 100 kHz.

I've also used the debugger to step through the individual lines of code. A breakpoint in the TC0 handler gets trigger at frequencies at or below 2287 Hz. Higher frequencies do not trigger the breakpoint, reconfirming that the interrupt routine doesn't fire.

```
#include <asf.h>

void TC0_Handler(void) {
    volatile uint32_t ul_dummy;

    pio_set_output(PIOD, PIO_PD20, HIGH, DISABLE, DISABLE);

    ul_dummy=TC0->TC_CHANNEL[0].TC_SR;  // read status register to clear interrupt flag.
    UNUSED(ul_dummy);

    pio_set_output(PIOD, PIO_PD20, LOW, DISABLE, DISABLE);
}


int main (void) {
    static uint32_t ul_sysclk, ul_div, ul_tcclks;
    uint32_t interrupt_frequency=2287; // in Hz

    sysclk_init();
    board_init();
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOC);
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOD);

    // Turn onboard LED off
    pio_set_output(PIOC, PIO_PC8, HIGH, DISABLE, DISABLE);

    // Timer and interrupt configuration
    ul_sysclk=sysclk_get_cpu_hz();
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_TC0);
    tc_find_mck_divisor(interrupt_frequency, ul_sysclk, &ul_div, &ul_tcclks, ul_sysclk);
    tc_init(TC0, 0, ul_tcclks | TC_CMR_CPCTRG);
    tc_write_rc(TC0, 0, (ul_sysclk/ul_div)/interrupt_frequency);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ((IRQn_Type) ID_TC0);
    tc_enable_interrupt(TC0, 0, TC_IER_CPCS);
    tc_start(TC0, 0);

    // Turn onboard LED on
    pio_set_output(PIOC, PIO_PC8, LOW, DISABLE, DISABLE);

    while(true){};
}
```

Comment: What is the clock divisor? With a limited timer counter range you use a prescaler to tick the timer at slower rate than at CPU sysclock speed. If the divisor is high then the timer ticks at slow rate so 100 kHz interrupts are not possible unless you make the timer to tick faster by changing the prescaler divisor to be smaller. Another thing is, what on earth would you do with 100kHz interrupts anyway? Sounds like either you are just testing or trying to do something in a way that is not good.

Comment: Based on debugging, in case I choose an interrupt frequency of 2287 Hz, the result of `(ul_sysclk/ul_div)/interrupt_frequency` is 16397 (`ul_sysclk` is 300000000 and `ul_div` is 8). If I choose 2288 Hz as interrupt frequency, `(ul_sysclk/ul_div)/interrupt_frequency` is 65588 (`ul_div` is 2).

Comment: I need an interrupt frequency of 100 kHz for audio processing.

Comment: You have a so called X-Y problem. It makes no sense to have a 100 kHz interrupt for audio processing. You would for example use DMA transfers and process the audio in small chunks of many samples, not a single sample at a time. If the MCU has no other way than a 100kHz timer interrupts to do it then it is a wrong MCU for the job.

Comment: You are making assumptions without really knowing what sort of processing I am planning. It's besides my question. I am still trying to get to 100 kHz. As far as I stand the scaling is calculated using `tc_find_mck_divisor`.

Comment: Indeed I don't know. Is the timer 16 or 32 bits? If it is 16-bit then the 65588 is a wrong value that does not fit into 16 bits. I can replicate the 2287 case but not 2288 case. It is not hard to calculate manually. 300 MHz divided by 100 kHz is 3000. Precaler 1. With prescaler 2, it's 1500. Prescaler 8 has 375 as the value. Most likely you need to put one less in the register.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106594/discussion-between-hansel-and-justme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Justme, I've managed to configure the interrupt for 100 kHz. The problem was that the timer wasn't set to a width of 32 bits and the function `tc_find_mck_divisor` doesn't 'know' that. The following code is a solution  that still works with a 16-b timer register (provided the master clock runs at 150 MHz):

```
int main (void) {

    sysclk_init();
    board_init();

    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOC);
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_PIOD);

    // Turn onboard LED off
    pio_set_output(PIOC, PIO_PC8, HIGH, DISABLE, DISABLE);

    // Timer and interrupt configuration for 100 kHz interrupt frequency
    pmc_enable_periph_clk(ID_TC0);
    tc_init(TC0, 0, 1 | TC_CMR_CPCTRG); // set prescaler to 8 (TCCLKS = 1)
    tc_write_rc(TC0, 0, 187);   // 150 MHz (MCK) divided by 8 (prescaler) divided by 100 kHz - 1.
    NVIC_EnableIRQ((IRQn_Type) ID_TC0);
    tc_enable_interrupt(TC0, 0, TC_IER_CPCS);
    tc_start(TC0, 0);

    // Turn onboard LED on
    pio_set_output(PIOC, PIO_PC8, LOW, DISABLE, DISABLE);

    while(true){};
}
```